# Original texture missing when using CustomModelData

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I was making a hammer in Minecraft and I replaced the shears texture to make it. And the custom model works like it's support to do, but when I get the shears without the CustomModelData the texture is missing. here's the resource pack
**Model** `RPack/models/hammer_model.json`

```
{
    "parent": "minecraft:item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "custom/glass_breaker"
    }
}
```

**OverideFile** `RPack/models/item/shears.json`

```
{
    "parent": "minecraft:item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "item/glass_breaker"
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "predicate": {
                "custom_model_data": 58022
            },
            "model": "glass_breaker/glass_breaker"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Texture** `RPack/textures/custom/hammer.json`

[image: Picture of the texure]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Hi, I think [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) might better suit your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just relisesed that I had the `Layer0` set to the my hammer model instead of the original model `minecraft:item/shears`. My model was overriding the orginal model.
This is what it looks like

```
    "parent": "minecraft:item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "minecraft:item/shears"
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "predicate": {
                "custom_model_data": 58022
            },
            "model": "glass_breaker/glass_breaker"
        }
    ]
}
```